# Class property initializer with async arrow function: event.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I have this construct:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  // ...
  handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Register</button>
    );
  }
```

but `e.preventDefault` is not recognized there:

If I remove `async`, it works.

***EDIT:***

I discovered that first argument in case of `async` is `this` instead of event. Also this works correctly:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => this._handleSubmit(e);

async _handleSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

It must be incorrect interfering of `async` and class property initializers in Babel

Babel:

Any suggestions?

***EDIT2:***

Looks related: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/391

Comment: I pasted that code into the Babel repl and it transpiled just fine: https://babeljs.io/repl  Are you sure the problem isn't elsewhere?

Comment: Yes it is valid syntax _if_ you enable stage-2 features.

Comment: Silly observation. But in your question title you refer as `event.preventDefault` (`event`) but in your code it's `e.preventDefault` (`e` argument). Are you sure that you're receiving e and calling from the same argument name?

Comment: I reproduced your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/1y0evLhy/  and it's working, Can you post how you're setting the `handleSubmit` callback? if you're using arrow functions, make sure you passed the event object (like the fiddle, second button)

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is connected with `react-hot-loader@3`